# Floating-point constant without using floating-point registers (Linux kernel module)

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I've developed a Linux kernel module and it requires the use of floating-point constants. I've recently encountered a kernel build that I need to work on which disables the use of floating-point registers for kernel modules.

The entirety of my *floating-point operations* could be compile-time and all that I need in the end is to have a variable on the heap that is the *in-memory binary equivalent* of a particular floating-point constant (the declared type of the variable is irrelevant). For example:

```
const float fval = 3.8 * 0.98 / 1000.0;
const int * const iptr = (const int *)&fval;
const int ival = *iptr;
```

It's convoluted but hopefully clarifies what I'm trying to accomplish. Basically, I need these steps to be performed during compilation such that I have the variable ival on the heap but without incurring the use of floating-point registers in the compiled code.

My hack-ish solution up to now has been to run the above code for the various floating-point constant values I need to represent and then manually transcribe their integer representation into my module code.

Expressed more clearly (and, yes, I actually need to use floating-point in some sense ... I just need to avoid use of floating-point registers in the compiled module). Suppose I have:

```
float val = 3.1415926;
```

And suppose it would be stored in memory as: 0xDA0F4940

Is there a way to get the compiler to populate a region of memory on the heap with 0xDA0F4940 without compiled in floating-point operations?

Comment: As a general guideline: Do not use floating point in kernel code. There is a very little that can be done with FP, which cannot be done without it.

Comment: The preprocessor does not work with floating point. However your posted C code should be optimized by any optimisation level >0  to just the form you need (no registers and no operations, just initialised variables).  Try it and look in the generated assembly.

Comment: XY problem. There is an easy and obvious way to get along without floats. Apply common maths. That code invokes undefined behaviour. And there is nothing allocated on the heap either.

Comment: Suggestion - Translate all FP to integer by multiplying them with some constant number - for above example - 380*98/1000

Comment: The provided code was pseudo-code.

In the end, I need there to be 4-bytes populated on the heap with what would be a particular floating-point value when I am in a context where I can use it as a floating-point.

The floating-point values are "configuration values" that my kernel module is providing a user-space program in a "configuration message".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using something like this:

```
union val {
    float fval;
    int ival;
};

static const union val my_val1 = { .fval = 3.8 * 0.98 / 1000.0 };

int *vp = whatever;
*vp = my_val1.ival;
```

The use of `static const` ought to be enough to prevent floating-point calculations at run-time.

Comment: Hopefully this will do the trick. And thanks for interpreting my use of "preprocessor" as what I actually meant, "any time prior to run-time".

Comment: Alright, I've verified that this is exactly what I needed.

I was surprised (but not highly) to find that I couldn't even do assignment or copying of float types without "using floating-point registers".

Even something like "static const float val1 = 3.1415;  float val2 = val1;"
was not being allowed.

Thanks again!